# Centering objects via jquery does not work on IE 11.0.2

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have pretty complicated algorithm to center main div in my HTML5 script (taking account side menu, ads, etc.), and it does not work in IE.

I managed to narrow down the problem to 20 lines of javascript:

```
function scaleToView()
{
$('#header').center();
}

$(function()
{
$.fn.extend({center: function ()
{
    pos = 0;
    this.css('left', (pos + (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                                    $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px');
    return this;
}});

scaleToView();

$( window ).resize(scaleToView);
});
```

The sample jfiddle is avaialble here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdaRw/6/

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE 11.0.2 (exact version: 11.0.9600.16476). I used debugger in IE, and it spit a lot of messages `Object does not support method: 'center'` (in Polish). When I attached debugger, I discovered that `center` method definition live through execution of `$(function()` but gets `undefined` when script is paused some time after

What is even more strange, it sometimes (rarely) actually works in IE, at first I thought it may be due to some kind of data race, but ultimately I was able to narrow down the problem to above lines of code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not just do this in css only?

Comment: `left` is not applied in IE

Comment: instead of `$(window).width`,  use `window.innerWidth;`. `$(window).width` doesn't work in IE

Comment: The problem is with a bug in jQuery.  JSFiddle uses iFrames, IE was giving an "access denied" in the console.  If you change it to "jQuery 1.x (edge)" (or "2.x (edge)"), it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdaRw/7/

Comment: @dstarh Because the entire positioning algorithm is much more complicated and cannot be done in CSS only

Comment: @RocketHazmat I see, I'll try to make another narrowed version of the problematic code

Comment: @RocketHazmat It seems the problem only appear after reloading the page (ie via internal link). On first page it wors. Is there any way to simulate that in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works. It's the fiddle that sucks! Just add `show` at the end of url and check in IE

Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdaRw/6/show/

Also, if you want, you can change the version of jQuery and it works like a charm.  Even if you go a a lower version of jQuery, like 1.9.1, still works

Comment: Thanks for showing the `show` trick, now I can update the problem description!

Comment: Strangely I cannot edit my question while an answer has been made, so I post a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097215/centering-divs-via-jquery-does-not-work-on-ie-11-0-2