# Centering divs via jquery does not work on IE 11.0.2

Tags: jquery

For whatever reason I can't edit [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095440/centering-objects-via-jquery-does-not-work-on-ie-11-0-2) after an answer has been made :-(

in IE 11.0.2 (exact version: 11.0.9600.16476)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go here with IE: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdaRw/16/show/
2. Click 'click me!' (the red one)
3. Rescale page

What I wanted to see:

1. The both divs should move while draggin window size

What I see instead:

1. Both divs only updates after scale has been made and 'click me!' has been clicked

Source:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZdaRw/16

```
function scaleToView()
{
    $('#header').center();
    $('#header2').center();
}

$(function()
{
    $.fn.extend({center: function ()
    {
        pos = 0;
        this.css('left', (pos + (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollLeft()) + 'px');
        return this;
    }});

    scaleToView();

    $( window ).resize(scaleToView);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong with the source, or is it a bug in IE?

Comment: using js here is quite overkill. why don't you center them using pure css?

Comment: Debug it down to the line that is giving you an unexpected value. Most likely it's the window width, or the outerwidth of the current element. I suggest also waiting until the window load event so that it takes into account the css and images included on the page (which will likely fix your issue). And as the comment above suggests, it's likely that whatever reason that you built this in JS rather than CSS can likely be solved using proper html structure and css.

Comment: @LorDex I am using much more complicated code, that handles left bar, ads, menu, etc. I cannot do this with pure css. I just narrowed down the example to the smallest code that still result in this problem

Comment: @KevinB debugging only shows that when `resize` event fires, the `center` function is `undefined` (but it is defined during call of `document.ready`). It seems that in IE you cannot set data breakpoint, that will break while value changes. I narrowed the code to this working (or should I said, non-working) example, actual code is much more complicated (that's the reason I can't use css for this)

Comment: You can't do a break, but you can do console.log if you have the console open which will allow you to log the values at the time that the function runs.

Comment: @KevinB I've done that already. Line 19 - `center` defined as function, Line 3 called from the resize event: `center` === `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, of course. you should never define a plugin inside of an event, instead, define it immediately. Currently you're defining it on dom ready, which is happening after the resize event.

Comment: @KevinB I moved `$.fn.extend` call out of event, it made no difference on IE - see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdaRw/17/show/

Comment: Does this one work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/ZdaRw/18/show/ it works in my IE10, and all the older emulated versions. I don't have IE11 to test with at the moment

Comment: @KevinB Not really: http://i.imgur.com/saHTBHT.jpg

Comment: Is your console open? i added a console.log, so you must have your console open to view it. (F12)

Comment: @KevinB I want to stress out, that it *only* breaks after you click the anchor tag, then try to resize. Here is new screen: http://i.imgur.com/Z4TPxF3.jpg

Comment: Why would you click the anchor tag? there are no events involved... Even so, clicking it makes no difference for me, it continues to work. all it does is reload the page.

Comment: @KevinB It's reloading the page. I know, it's strange, but ordinal refresh (via `F5`) doesn't break this script, only page travel via `anchor`. I have this problem in pretty complicated multipage application, I narrowed it to this point. I am getting more and more confident that this is actually a bug in IE, but such statements are a bit too high to be stated without absolute conviction that there is no stupid error in my code...

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code, refreshing in either way should not have had any differing outcome.

Comment: @KevinB I know, refreshing should have no effect, but it does. Okay, let's scout through Microsoft Feedback site if this is a known bug